# No rows returned if joined table does not return results

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using multiple inner joins right now, but one of the tables may contain no results at all.

Below is the query that I'm currently using

```
SELECT
   property.id,
   full_address,
   street_address,
   street.street,
   city.city as city,
   state.state_code as state_code,
   zipcode.zipcode as zipcode, 
   property_history.date_event AS event_date,
   property_history.event AS event
FROM
    property 
    INNER JOIN street  ON street.id = property.street_id 
    INNER JOIN city    ON city.id = property.city_id
    INNER JOIN state   ON state.id = property.state_id
    INNER JOIN zipcode ON zipcode.id = property.zipcode_id
    INNER JOIN property_history ON property_history.property_id = property.id
WHERE
    full_address = ?
```

Right now if `property_history` does not return any rows then I would not get anything. I assume I need to use another type of join?

I still want to get the `property.id`, `full_address`, `street_address`, etc even though the `property_history` is empty.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
LEFT JOIN property_history ON property_history.property_id = property.id
```